# angular js ui-Router : Child view overwrites views already displayed in parent

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

With reference to the below mentioned state structure :

```
 parent
   |->leftTree
   |->rightTree
```

In my ***Parent*** state template i have 2 ui-views .

leftTree is config to display its content in ui-view="h1" and rightTree in ui-view="h2"

```
<div ui-view = "h1"></div>
<div ui-view = "h2"></div>
```

and 2 Buttons

```
<button type="button" ui-sref="lefttree()" class="btn btn-default">left</button>
<button type="button" ui-sref="righttree()" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
```

When i click on button left -> the "leftTree" template is displayed under ui-view = "h1"

***But when i click on button right*** -> the "rightTree" template is displayed under ui-view = "h2" but the information in ui-view = "h1" is deleted (i mean ui-view= "h1" is completely empty).

Is this the expected behaviour .
How can i preserve the information in ui-view = "h1"

Please find the code below :

```
let a = angular.module("app", ["ui.router"]);
a.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", function(statepro, urlPro) {

  statepro.state("parent" , {
    url:"/parent",
    template : `<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                  <button type="button" ui-sref="parent.lefttree()" class="btn btn-default">left</button>
                  <button type="button" ui-sref="parent.righttree()" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
                </div>
                <div ui-view = "h1"></div>
                <div ui-view = "h2"></div>`,
    controller : function(){
      console.log("creating parent");
    }
  });

  statepro.state("parent.lefttree" , {
    url:"/lefttree",
    views : {
      "h1" : {
        template : `<div class="panel panel-default" style = "width : 30%">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Left Tree</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          left tree
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      </div>`,
        controller : function(){
                        console.log("created left tree");
                      }
      }
    }

  });

  statepro.state("parent.righttree" , {
    url:"/righttree",
    views : {
      "h2" : {
        template : `<div class="panel panel-default" style = "width : 30%">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Right tree</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          right tree
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      </div>`,
        controller : function(){
                        console.log("created right tree");
                      }
      }
    }

  });

urlPro.otherwise("/parent");

}]);
```

thanks

Comment: Please also add code for lefttree() and righttree()

Comment: @ Hassan  i have added the code .. thanks

Comment: Are you trying to show `lefttree` and `righttree` next to each other?

Comment: @joe .. yes .. what i want is the data in leftTree should not be destroyed when righttree shows its information

Comment: @Max Do you want the views for `lefttree` and `righttree` to only show up once the links are clicked? Or do you want them to display immediately?

Comment: @joe .. only when the links are clicked .. view's should persist and not destroyed when second view is displayed .. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding named views. Only one state can be activated at a time. If you want to accomplish this through states you would need to have `parent`, `parent.lefttree`, `parent.righttree`, and an additional state to show both (i.e. `parent.bothtrees`).

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L09t33e5/2/) contains an example of this solution. Notice the duplication in state `parent.bothTrees`